# generic/wildcard types in method call?

Tags: java, generics

I am quite new to Java and try to create a small game to learn the language. Currently, I have the following problem: I have I class called "Task" with attributes like "taskName"(String), "level" (Integer), "propability" (Double) and so on.

I read in several tasks from a textfile and write them to an object of class "TaskList" which extends from ArrayList. As methods of "TaskList", I want to implement sorting and filtering algorithms for the list (e.g. "delete all Tasks below level 3").

I would prefer not to write a filter method for every single attribute, but to write a method which is able to filter every attribute, depending on the input.

As far as I know already, this should be possible by using generic or wildcard types but I do not understand how to use them properly.

My method head looks like this at the moment:

```
public TaskList removeTasks(String variableName, String variableValue){
```

In my idea, "variableName" should always be a string, but "variableValue" could be of several types. I thought I could use a switch block at the beginning of the method to determine what to do with "variableValue". eg:

```
switch(variableName)
  case "taskName":
    [Code]

  case "level":
    [Code]

  [...]
```

So currently, my problem is: How to say Java that "variableValue" can be of several types?

If you have other suggestion how to solve my problem that would be fine also. As I said, I am not very experienced concerning Java.

**Edit:** I tried the syntax NimChimpsky proposed and it works in the first instance, but below, I have a new problem. When I check if "variableValue" is equal to the attribute of the current Task, I get an "Incompatible operand types int and T" error. How can I prevent that?

Code snippet:

```
switch(variableName){
  case "level":
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){                   
      currentTask = this.get(i);
      if (currentTask.getLevel() == variableValue)
        this.remove(i);
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an `enum` might work

Comment: There's so much to be learned about Java.  I'm concerned this approach may be counterproductive if your goal is to learn Java in the sense of being able to use it for real-world purposes.

Answer (score 0):

use Object as the parameter type for value, is the simplest.

But using gernerics, removes the risk of cast exceptions at runtime.

```
public <T> TaskList removeTasks(String variableName, T variableValue){}
```